# Can't run AWS SAM CLI under Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to create a Docker image for [AWS SAM CLI](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli), but invoking any function gives an error: "Unable to import module 'index'". I can run the same test case outside of Docker sucessfully. You can clone the test case [here](https://github.com/dc7/docker-sam-local) or see the files below.

I already tried the following:

- Setting permissions of files and parent folder to 777 (or 755).
- Disabling SELinux in the Docker daemon (or enabling it).
- Running Docker under privileged mode (or not).
- I get the same error using an old (SAM 0.22) [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cnadiminti/aws-sam-local/).
- Running the same function locally as described below (works).
- Zipping the folder and running on AWS (works).

These solutions probably don't apply:

- The format of the zip file incorrectly including the parent folder (no zip file is used).
- Issues related to NPM dependencies or node_modules (index.js has no dependencies).
- Compilation errors in index.js (syntax is correct, works outside of Docker and on AWS).
- The volume is being mounted on the host as described [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli#remote-docker).

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk add --no-cache py-pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir aws-sam-cli
```

event.json

```
{}
```

index.js

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    return callback(null, {
        'body': 'Hello, World!'
    });
};
```

template.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: HelloWorld
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Timeout: 300
```

To run SAM locally:

```
sam local invoke -t template.yml -e event.json HelloWorld
```

Running SAM locally succeeds:

```
{"body":"Hello, World!"}
```

To run SAM under Docker:

```
docker build -t hello .
docker run \
    -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    hello sam local invoke -t template.yml -e event.json HelloWorld
```

Running SAM under Docker fails:

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 x86_64

Docker version: 18.03.1-ce

SAM CLI version: 0.3.0

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference the directory relative to your host hard drive, not the first docker container drive tree.

To do so with SAM cli, use option `--docker-volume-basedir "$PWD"` (or `-v "$PWD"`) on `sam local invoke`.

> From: `sam local invoke --help`
>
> `--docker-volume-basedir value`, `-v value`  Optional. Specifies the location basedir where the SAM file exists. If the Docker is running on a remote machine, you must mount the path where the SAM file exists on the docker machine and modify this value to match the remote machine. [`$SAM_DOCKER_VOLUME_BASEDIR`]

So with your above setup, to run SAM under docker:

```
docker build -t hello .
docker run \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    hello sam local invoke -t template.yml -e event.json HelloWorld -v $(pwd)
```